# Histograma no R

Tags: r, histograma

Estou tentando fazer um histograma de idade (a idade mínima é 0 e a máxima é 115 anos) e quero representar graficamente a frequência. No entanto, não gostaria que a frequência fosse para todas as idades, pois não cabe na figura. Pode ser a cada 5 anos, tentei usar break, mas não deu certo. Alguém tem uma dica?
Para ver a figura:

https://photos.app.goo.gl/X9jCn6nUELxFpy6j6

```
ggplot(BASE, aes(x=idade)) + 
  geom_histogram(bins = 20, color = "darkblue", fill = "lightblue") +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Blues") + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues") +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Idade", breaks = seq(0, 120, 5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Frequência") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20) +
  theme(legend.position = "right", legend.title = element_blank()) +
  geom_text(stat='count', aes(label=..count..), vjust=-1)
```

Também tentei incluir outra variável: gênero. E obtenha na imagem os valores referentes às frequências de cada gênero centralizado. Mas a visualização também era terrível, pois representava todas as idades e não 5 em 5.

```
s <- ggplot(BASE, aes(x = idade, fill = genero))
s + geom_bar(position = "stack") + 
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Blues") + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues") +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Idade", breaks = seq(0, 120, 5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Frequência") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=1)) + 
  geom_text(stat='count', aes(label=..count..), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),size=4)
```

Para ver a figura:

https://photos.google.com/album/AF1QipMQm6n5ivZorCK34nuk4L52ncDS4YzxApuvNx6d/photo/AF1QipO7Ix3HXt9sXJ_5UsCJfGjJZnR4Y21XqI7Y4tjR

Comment: Bem-vinda ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) (principalmente no uso da função `dput`) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível. Além disso, evite utilizar links para sites externos em sua pergunta. É possível adicionar as figuras diretamente no post.

Answer (score 1):

Para traçar uma densidade do histograma, use

```
aes(y = ..density..)
```

Aqui vão dois exemplos, um com o número de classes e outro com a amplitude de cada classe.

Primeiro crio uma base.

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(2021)
n <- 1e4
BASE <- data.frame(idade = sample(0:115, n, TRUE))
```

Agora determino quantas classes vai ter o histograma com a fórmula de Sturges. O R base também tem [funções para outras fórmulas](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/nclass.html).

```
bins <- nclass.Sturges(BASE$idade)

ggplot(BASE, aes(x = idade)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), 
                 bins = bins, 
                 fill = "blue",
                 color = "lightblue") +
  geom_density(aes(y=..density..))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E com a amplitude das classes usa-se o argumento `binwidth`.

```
ggplot(BASE, aes(x = idade)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), 
                 binwidth = 5, 
                 fill = "blue",
                 color = "lightblue") +
  geom_density(aes(y=..density..))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigada, me ajudou muito.

Answer (score 1):

Para representar as idades em intervalos de 5 anos, use `binwidth` ao invés de `bins`. Para os rótulos, pode usar `stat_bin` com `geom = "text"`. Como não postou uma amostra dos seus dados, estou simulando alguns. Não incluí as personalizações do gráfico para ressaltar os pontos relevantes do código:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(376)
dados <- data.frame(idade = sample(0:115, 1e4, TRUE),
                    genero = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 1e4, TRUE))

ggplot(dados, aes(idade)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 5, color = "black") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 115, 5)) +
  stat_bin(aes(y = ..count.., label = ..count..),
           geom = "text", binwidth = 5, vjust = -.5)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para os dados separados por gênero, use `position_stack` para garantir a posição correta dos rótulos:

```
ggplot(dados, aes(idade, fill = genero)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 5, color = "black") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 115, 5)) +
  stat_bin(aes(y = ..count.., label = ..count..),
           geom = "text", binwidth = 5,
           position = position_stack(vjust = .5))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigada pela ajuda! Mas nesse caso, as contagens que estão nas frequências  representam os intervalos da seguinte forma: 0 a 2 anos, 3 a 7 anos, 8 a 12 anos, 13 a 17 anos e assim por diante. Eu gostaria que fosse de 5 em 5 anos, ou seja: 0 a 4 anos, 5 a 10 anos ...

Comment: Adicione as opções `boundary = 0` e `closed = "left"` (veja a ajuda pra geom_histogram para detalhes). Edite a pergunta para especificar que deseja esses intervalos.